# Extract degrees of freedom from a fixest feols object

Tags: r, fixest

simple question:
Can I extract the final degrees of freedom after a `feols` estimation using the `fixest` package?

```r
res = feols(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length | Species, iris)
summary(res)
```

I know that there are many fancy ways to specify the df in fixest, but I'd just want the result (depending on which option I choose).

For example in the `lfe` package using `felm`, I can do so easily like this:

```r
res = felm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length | Species | 0 | 0, iris)
res$df
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is:  `degrees_freedom(res, "resid", vcov = "iid")`

---

The VCOV has an influence on the values produced by `degrees_freedom`. Here's an explanation.

By default:

- the VCOV is clustered wrt the first fixed-effect (if FEs are present)
- when the VCOV is clustered, FEs that are nested with the cluster are dropped in the DoF calculation (to avoid over-penalization)

The number 3 obtained in `degrees_freedom(res, "k")` *is not* the number of fixed-effects. It's the number of regressors, excluding the nested FEs (and adding the intercept).

By changing the way the VCOV is computed, you change the output of `degrees_freedom`. Here the nestedness is the problem, so you can remove it:

```
degrees_freedom(res, "resid", vcov = cluster ~ ssc(fixef.K = "full"))
#> [1] 145
```

But the easiest way is to use an "iid" VCOV.

---

Agreed the help page only implicitly refers to this by saying that the values depend on the type of VCOV. This could be clearer, I'll try to improve that!

Comment: The beauty of SO - getting the developer to answer your question :))
Thanks for your work on this excellent package Laurent, much appreciated!! Also thanks for making this clearer in the help page!

Answer (score 3):

There is a `degrees_freedom`

```
> degrees_freedom(res, type = "k")
[1] 3
> degrees_freedom(res, type = "resid")
[1] 147
> degrees_freedom(res, type = "t")
[1] 2
```

By changing the `type`, can get different degrees of freedom i.e `?degrees_freedom` shows

> type - Character scalar, equal to "k", "resid", "t". If "k", then the number of regressors is returned. If "resid", then it is the "residuals degree of freedom", i.e. the number of observations minus the number of regressors. If "t", it is the degrees of freedom used in the t-test. Note that these values are affected by how the VCOV of x is computed, in particular when the VCOV is clustered.

---

Or may use

```
fitstat(res, "g", simplify = TRUE)
```

Or could be

```
unname(res$fixef_sizes)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply - but are you sure it really shows the degrees of freedom? The felm df for the same estimation are 145 - while your answer gives 3. Doesn't your solution just show me the fixed effect number? 

Also, which package is the `degrees_freedom` from?

Comment: @MoritzSchwarz it is from the `fixest` package.  According to `?degrees_freedom` - `Simple utility to extract the degrees of freedom from a fixest estimation.`

Comment: @MoritzSchwarz I updated the post.  I am not sure if the 145 is based 147 - 2 or so

Comment: Ha, note to self: always update the packages you are asking a question about... ;) 
Thanks, now I found the function. 
Interesting though that the df are different... When using `lm` and `lm_robust`, I also get 145. And for felm, df.residual and df are the same (also 145)

Comment: @MoritzSchwarz I don't know all the details.  But I find that they use different algos in `exactDOF`

Comment: @MoritzSchwarz Can you check this statement `The standard errors are adjusted for the reduced degrees of freedom coming from the dummies which are implicitly present.`. I am not sure if the 0, 0, will have any effect

Answer (score 2):

We may find them after `summary` in the `attr`ibutes of the scaled covariance matrix, check `str(summary(res))`.

```
attr(summary(res)$cov.scaled, 'dof.K')
# [1] 3
```